# Migrating ASP.NET MVC 5 bundling "versions" to MVC 6

Tags: gulp, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-bundling

The bundling feature is excluded from MVC 6 and the suggested method is to do bundling using gulp tasks.

Using bundling we used to get a random **string** at the end of the included css/javascript file url(s). This **string** was very important because once you changed anything in your css/javascript then a new **string** would be generated which would force browsers to load the new version(s) of the file(s).

So if you had 3 css files they would be bundled into one and they would look like this:

```
<link href="/Style/css?v=sGJNctjkEuiEEdR68fh0dDt7bwrHIbu_EfQtgon7oYc1" rel="stylesheet">
```

How can we achieve the same functionality in MVC 6? I don't know whether gulp can help here or not but I am already using gulp to do minification and bundling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For beta6 set `asp-file-version="true"` to retain cache-busting behavior:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-file-version="true" />
```

For beta7, use `asp-append-version="true"`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Apparently as of beta 7, you need to use "asp-append-version" as per this link https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/149 can you please amend your answer so I can mark it as answer.