# How to disable browser cache in ASP.NET core rc2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I tried this Middleware but the browser still saving files.

I want user will always get the last version of js and css files.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = context =>
            context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try adding an `Expires` header as well:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    OnPrepareResponse = context =>
    {
        context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
        context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
    }
});
```

Another approach would be to add a querystring that changes to the end of your requests in development. Middleware would not be required in this case.

```
<environment names="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css?@DateTime.Now.Ticks" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css?@DateTime.Now.Ticks" />
</environment>
```

Comment: If you do Headers.Add(, then it will fail if a middleware already added the header, therefore, use Response.Headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0"; etc.

Answer (score 45):

Disabling browser cache in ASP.NET core:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [ResponseCache(NoStore =true, Location =ResponseCacheLocation.None)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Another way would be using an ASP-Attribute when you link your files in your `_Layout.cshtml` by using `asp-append-version` you will add a fresh hash everytime the file changed, so writing:

```
<script src="~/js/minime.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

will in the end lead to:

```
<script src="/js/minime.js?v=Ynfdc1vuMOWZFfqTjfN34c2azo3XiIfgfE-bba1"></script>
```

so you get caching and the latest version out of the box.

Comment: The hash is defined in LinkTagHelper, currently a SHA256-hash (SHA: Secure Hash Algorithms): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342643/how-does-javascript-version-asp-append-version-work-in-asp-net-core-mvc

Answer (score 3):

```cs
[ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, Duration = 0, NoStore = true)]
```

Try adding an annotation above the controller class.It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but the posted solution didn't work for me.
What was working is that I added a middleware, which adds the headers.

```
    app.Use(async (httpContext, next) =>
    {
        httpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
        httpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Expires] = "-1";
        await next();
    });
```