# StaticFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse does not get called for index.html

Tags: c#, node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I'm currently trying to disable the caching for `index.html` for my Angular SPA with a .NET Core 2.2 backend.

I'm doing this according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38231739/how-to-disable-browser-cache-in-asp-net-core-rc2) by setting an `OnPrepareResponse` action for my `StaticFileOptions`.

But the `Cache-Control` header never gets sent. When I set a breakpoint in the OnPrepareResponse action I break for everyfile *except* `index.html`

What am I missing here? How can I actually control the cache for the `index.html` file?

[image]

```cs
// I've changed nothing else in the default ASP.NET Core/Angular template
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ...

    var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = context =>
        {
            // Breakpoint for next line hits for following files
            // 1: styles.61d14a95058dbe9da495.css
            // 2: runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js
            // 3: polyfills.7a0e6866a34e280f49e7.js
            // 4: main.d9791b5a6df420d81994.js
            // 5: favicon.ico
            if (context.File.Name == "index.html")
            {
                context.Context.Response.Headers
                    .Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
                context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
                context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");
            }
        }
    };

    app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this code to see if it work for you

```
      app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
                {
                    var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                    headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                    {
                        Public = true,
                        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                    };

                }
            });


     app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
                spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions()
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = ctx => {
                        var headers = ctx.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
                        headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
                        {
                            Public = true,
                            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(0)
                        };
                    }
                };

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response :) This would disable the caching for all files, but I only want to disable it for index.html (as the js and css files are versioned anyways). I will play around with your soultion a bit if I can adapt it for my needs. But I've also just found a solution which works (see my answer)

Comment: @Staeff : I believe this answer by @TonyNgo is correct. The reason why the the OP's code doesn't work is that the `index.html` is processed by `app.UseSpa()` instead of `app.UseSpaStatic()`. Only other `css`/`js`/... static files are served by `app.UseSpaStatic()`.

Comment: I think the section under UseSpa is correct, but in the section inside `UseSpaStaticFiles` you should remove the `OnPrepareResponse` handler. That way you would only be disabling the cache for the default file path, and you would be enabling the cache for the other static files.

Comment: I'm using WebView2 with Kestrel server inside the windows WPF app.
Last two comments above are correct. `UseStaticFiles` does nothing, `UseSpaStaticFiles` serves all css/js. `UseSpa` serves `index.html`

Comment: For anyone else running into the OnPrepareResponse simply not running, I found that the spa.UseAngularCliServer in dev mode prevents it from being hit. If you "npm run build" the spa app and then comment out the spa.UseAngularCliServer lines, it will start hitting the OnPrepareResponse.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution I came up with looks like this. I'm not sure I love this solution but at least it works.

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        var requestPath = context.Request.Path.Value;

        if (requestPath.EndsWith("index.html"))
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "0");
        }

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });

    await next();
});
```

Comment: This approach does work. But it does not explain why your original code doesn't work. IMO, @Tony Ngo 's reply answers the reason.