# .NET Core Avoiding StaticFileMiddleware To Return Response 304 Not Modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using `StaticFileMiddleware` in my .NET Core Application with default options.

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

I understand that if there is a request and the requested file was not modified, it returns `304 Not Modified`.

But, is there many way to make the middleware to always return the file every time clients request for it? No matter if the file was modified or not, just always return it, and do not return `304`.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want this? Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235096/34092 an option?

Comment: Why? The client has a file that it fetched before. Just make sure that you "touch" any file you deploy and everything should work just fine.

Comment: Hi @mjwills, I do not want to disable cache at all. I want to let client decide, to cache or to request a file again.

Comment: Hi @JeremyLakeman , I am developing web app for embedded browser. The problem is, sometimes the browser fails to cache image. And then it requests the file again, but my middleware returns 304. It causes missing image on the page. The only way to fix is to restart device.

Comment: Does setting the cache location to `Client` help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @mjwills It seems like the one I need. I will try. Thank you.