# Service/extension for getting a cache-busting 'version string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, offline-caching

### Background

I have an application where 3 views utilize html5 offline app functionality. As such, I have an app manifest generated in a razor view. A cut-down version of this view may look like the following:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
/site.min.css
/site.min.js
```

In order for the offline app to function correctly, the cached files must exactly match those requested by offline pages within the app. However, I would like to apply a 'cache-busting' version string to the js/css resources referenced in this manifest. For HTML tags, this is supported by the `ScriptTagHelper` but I have not found any helpers/extension methods which support this for plain URLs (as required in the above manifest).

With reference to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342643/how-does-javascript-version-asp-append-version-work-in-asp-net-core-mvc), I have resolved this by injecting a [`FileVersionProvider`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/Internal/FileVersionProvider.cs) into my manifest view and using the `AddFileVersionToPath()` method as follows:

```razor
@inject FileVersionProvider versionProvider
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
@versionProvider.AddFileVersionToPath("/site.min.css")
@versionProvider.AddFileVersionToPath("/site.min.js")
```

However, the [`FileVersionProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.taghelpers.internal.fileversionprovider?view=aspnetcore-2.0) class is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Internal` namespace which does not fill me with confidence form a maintenance perspective.

Finally, my implementation of the DI setup for this is not exactly ideal (see below). I don't like the fact that I need to make calls to `GetService()` and surely I should be specifying a specific `MemoryCache`?

```
services.AddSingleton<FileVersionProvider>(s => 
    new FileVersionProvider(
        s.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>()?.WebRootFileProvider, 
        s.GetService<IMemoryCache>(), 
        new PathString("") ));
```

### Question

Has anyone had a requirement to create a link to a js/css resource with a version string before? If so, is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [this extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45088852/3276634)? It worked for me on ASP.NET Core 2.1 LTS without any depencency injection, just the extension method. Should work in 2.0 as well if you still use it.

I had a similar use-case where SCEditor loads CSS from a path passed by JavaScript.

```
@{
    // Without version hash cache buster, the editor internally cache the request and we don't get the new stylesheet - even not with CTRL + F5
    string editorThemePath = this.AddFileVersionToPath("/css/my-editor-theme.css");
}
<script>
      sceditor.create(editorTextarea, {
            // ...
            style: '@editorThemePath'
      })
</script>
```

Generated HTML

```
<script>
      sceditor.create(editorTextarea, {
            style: '/css/my-editor-theme.css?v=sRU_qBg7xyQElPLskjekOlvSHdRF2Ap1leTP8ui4CaI',
      })
</script>
```

Keep in mind that this implementation requires paths relative to `wwwroot`. So in this case, `/css/my-editor-theme.css` is in `wwwroot/css/my-editor-theme.css`.

Could be changed if you replace the first parameter of `FileVersionProvider` from `hostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` to `hostingEnvironment.ContentRootFileProvider`. But I havent' tested what are the side effects and security concerns of this, so you should stay on `wwwroot` if possible since this folder is designed to be public accessable.

Comment: Thanks @Lion. It was pre 2.2 when I first tried this, so good to see there is a better alternative.